# Get custom url in phtml file Magento 2

Tags: php, sql, database, magento, magento2

I have post in posts table.
I need to display post on page like this /id where id is post_id.
And i can get post from id like magento/5
On post page get data about page like title, text, ...
how i cam do that ?

Answer (score 0):

try creating a Post model Factory  in your block class and you can pass the post_id as a filter and be able to get the other data you want